# _this.files.filter is not a function ng2-uploader angular2 file upload

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am newbie to Angular2 and Implementing file upload in Angular2 using ng2-uploader module.
the uploading is working fine but i am getting below errors on console.
can any one help me sort out this

After file uploading I am getting the console error like below:

```
EXCEPTION: _this.files.filter is not a function
 at ng-file-select.ts:42
at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (async.js:105)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at EventEmitter.Subject.next (Subject.js:55)
at EventEmitter.emit (async.js:79)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (ng2-uploader.ts:111)
at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (zone.js:1242)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:367)
at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:264)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:366)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:166)
at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:420)
```

and iam facing issue with xhr request also
Xhr request is firing twice for single file upload

Pls suggest me any solutions to resolve the issues

Comment: We are going to need to see some code

Answer (score 0):

I am also using ng2-uploader for upload file. its showing me same issue.But if i did not return anything in then it it is hitting twice to server side and same file uploading two times.